# Set AutoLayout Size Class Programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

With iOS 8 and Xcode 6, in storyboards we now have the screen size grid letting us select a size class. Where you can select layout formatting for the different screen sizes.

I have found this brilliantly helpful, as it allows me to set the base constraints and then unique ones for each screen size.

My question is, can you do this programmatically? I create my `NSLayoutConstraint` as normal but I need to be able to specify different constraints for different screen sizes.

Comment: They are called Size Class.

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed that! Now if only there were a way to specify size classes programatically with `NSLayoutConstraint` or similar.

Answer (score 14):

iOS 8 introduces the [`active`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010628-CH1-DontLinkElementID_6) property on `NSLayoutConstraint`. It allows you to activate or deactivate a constraint. There are also methods to activate/deactivate multiple constraints.

```
+ (void)activateConstraints:(NSArray *)constraints
+ (void)deactivateConstraints:(NSArray *)constraints
```

- Keep your constraints in arrays when creating them programmatically.
- Create an array for each of the layouts you need.
- Activate/Deactivate whatever set of constraints you need from within `willTransitionToTraitCollection`

Comment: Thanks but maybe in 2017 is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit confusing & hard to find in the documentation because a "size class" isn't actually a "Class" like NSObject. They're really defined in an enum/typedef called: [UIUserInterfaceSizeClass](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIUserInterfaceSizeClass)

The way to get the horizontal & vertical size class for a view is with a [UITraitCollection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITraitCollection_ClassReference/)

Class/Type methods for UITraitCollection allow you to create one based on a particular display scale (e.g. retina or not), from an array of other trait collections, with a UI idiom (iPad/iPhone), or specific horizontal & vertical options (compact, regular), but to be honest I'm not sure yet how you'd use this...

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24716136/where-to-update-autolayout-constraints-when-size-changes) discusses updating constraints when the traitCollection changes, using `willTransitionToTraitCollection(newCollection: UITraitCollection!,
    withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator!)`

You're right that both the UITraitCollection and its properties are readonly, but clearly you can create a new collection for some reason, and handle layout changes when the traitCollection changes.

[This previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331040/uitraitcollection-clarification) is pretty similar & links to an Apple article about using Adaptive Layout. Also check the WWDC video "Building Adaptive Apps with UIKit."

Comment: I should have the time to watch the WWDC videos tomorrow. However, you can't set the traitCollection property of a view or layout constraint, only read. So how would you apply a constraint to belong to a certain trait collection? Its an interesting change they've brought in, I rather like it so far.

Comment: Found & added a related question about changing constraints. There are clearly methods for creating new UITraitCollections, and passing them to methods when the view `willTransitionToTraitCollection` ... but I haven't played with it enough or watched the video in several months. Time for me to take another look too! To me the process & documentation for Adaptive Layout is pretty poor and confusing considering it's such a big new feature... Will figure it out eventually!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you can set the size class programmatically, however, it's a bit of a pain. You must call "setOverrideTraitCollection" but from the parent view controller, not the one you actually wished to make a trait change to.

In my situation, I wanted to change the Master VC of a split view controller on iPad to look differently than the one on the iPhone, however, they are both set to Compact width / Regular height by default. So I subclassed the Master's nav controller and added code to set the Master's traits to Regular width when it's not an iPhone.

Swift code:

```
class MasterNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if (self.traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom != .Phone) {
            let newTraitCollection = UITraitCollection(horizontalSizeClass: .Regular)
            self.setOverrideTraitCollection(newTraitCollection, forChildViewController: self.topViewController)
        }
    }

}
```

I hope this helps someone looking for a similar solution.

Comment: You set the size class manually but what to do with constraints previously declared? How to detect correctly which trait they belong?

Comment: Constraints are set for each size class in storyboard (using the device icons at the bottom). Here's a video from WWDC 2016 where they go into how that's changed recently. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/236/

Comment: I know about storyboard but the question was about constraints declared programmatically