# Can I add constraints based on size class in viewDidLoad programmatically?

Tags: ios, ios8

Previously I used adaptive layout in my project using size class, I were able to add/install constraints based on the size class.
But now I am adding constraint in viewDidLoad. I want to use adaptive layout feature without using XIB file. 
Is that possible ?

Comment: yes, you can create NSLayoutConstraint object, then add the constraint to the view that you want to .

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26370038/792677) that references  `UITraitCollection`.