# iPhone 6 Plus landscape issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, rotation, landscape

In my app, I have to block screen rotation in most of my ViewControllers. Only 1 ViewController should be able to rotate. In iPhone 5-5,and 6 it works well, but running un iPhone 6 Plus, when I rotate to landscape in that ViewController, everything dissapear. Only the main view is visible. Is there a configuration for 6+ to work like the other iPhones? I guess it's because it acts like the iPad when you rotate the screen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[UITraitCollection Clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331040/uitraitcollection-clarification)

As it sais in the answer: "The iPhone 6+ has a regular width in landscape mode."

In my storyboard I had width:Compact, so it was working in devices with smaller screens.

I solved overriding this method in the ViewController:

```
-(UITraitCollection *)traitCollection{
    return [UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithHorizontalSizeClass:UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact];
}
```